# Two sets with equal cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose two non-empty sets A and B, and A is a subset of B, and A is not equal to B. Is |A| = |B| possible?

Comment: This is literally a definition (of many possible definitions) of a set being infinite.

Comment: Yes.   A = even integers and B = integers.

Comment: If they are both infinite sets, this is entirely possible. What if A is the set of even integers and B is the set of integers?

Comment: I've only delved into some basic set theory, but if A and B are both infinite, how does infinity = infinity make sense? If A is an uncountable set and B is countably infinite set, does that also imply |A|=|B|?

Comment: Eventually you will be asked to prove that if $X$ is an infinite set and $A$ is a finite subset of $X$ then $|X| = |X-A|$.  This is very possible and very common.

Comment: infinity = infinity does *not* make sense.  Infinite means not finite.  But there are different ways a set can be infinite.  It could be countably infinite, it could be uncountably infinite.  If A is countable and B is not then |A| < |B|.  (But here are different ways a set can be uncountably infinite as well) But neither of the sets has "cardinality equal to infinity".  Such a sentence doesn't make sense and is not well-defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If A is an uncountable set and B is countably infinite set, does that also imply $\vert A\vert=\vert B\vert$?

Of course not. What **is** true is that $\vert A\vert=\vert B\vert$ **can sometimes happen** even if $A\subsetneq B$. For example:

- $\vert \{$even integers$\}\vert=\vert\mathbb{Z}\vert$
- $\vert\mathbb{Z}\vert=\vert\mathbb{Q}\vert$
- $\vert\mathbb{R}\vert=\vert\mathbb{C}\vert$.

(Remember that when we say "$\vert X\vert=\vert Y\vert$," what we're really saying is "there is a bijection from $X$ to $Y$." Can you find bijections demonstrating the above equalities?)

On the other hand, of course $\vert\mathbb{Z}\vert\not=\vert\mathbb{R}\vert$. So:

> Just knowing $A\subsetneq B$ tells you nothing about the relative cardinalities of $A$ and $B$, except obviously that $\vert A\vert\le\vert B\vert$.

---

It's worth observing that (assuming the axiom of choice) every infinite set gives rise to an example of this: if $B$ is infinite and $b\in B$, then (again, assuming the axiom of choice) we have $\vert B\vert=\vert B\setminus\{b\}\vert$ - that is, **removing a single element from an infinite set doesn't change its size**. And in fact if $C\subseteq B$ with $\vert C\vert<\vert B\vert$ and $B$ is infinite, then $\vert B\vert=\vert B\setminus C\vert$ - **removing a small number of elements from an infinite set doesn't change its size**.

But this doesn't at all imply that every infinite set has the same cardinality as every other infinite set *(so "infinity equals infinity" is a nonsense slogan - it's exactly as nonsensical, and in exactly the same way, as "finite equals finite")*, and it's also worth noting that this does in fact require the axiom of choice.